# Parsing data from website and inputting into Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the price of this coin (https://polygon.poocoin.app/tokens/0x4ac6e3cda66967f1286da690129a33638f9e7088), and have it automatically be put in a google sheet, with it automatically refreshing once every few minutes preferably (or faster, if possible). I tried using IMPORTXML and IMPORTHTML, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I tried =IMPORTXML("https://polygon.poocoin.app/tokens/0x4ac6e3cda66967f1286da690129a33638f9e7088" ,"//span[@class='text-success']"), but it says "ERROR: Imported content is empty.".

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will work, but if you export the table as a HTML file by following the instructions on [this website](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v2019/page/enterprise-cloud/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/using-the-workbench/cloud-using-recorder-extract-table-data.html), you could then use `=IMPORTHTML()` to add it to your Google Sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that'd make it the value static as opposed to it auto-updating!

Comment: oh, true - apologies.